# How can I have Module::Build compile and link my small C program?

Tags: c, perl, compilation, module-build

I have a simple C source file in a `src` directory in my project. My `Build.PL` contains the following lines:

```
c_source => ['src'],
extra_compiler_flags => ['-std=c99']
```

However, all this does is compile it to a `.o` file in the `src` directory corresponding to the C file. What I'd really like is to have it compiled and linked to form an executable, then put in my `bin` directory.

Is this possible and advisable with `Module::Build`?

Comment: That builds an object file to be linked with Perl. It should have its own build process. You could launch that build process from M::B, I imagine, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though ikegami said this is not the proper way to do things (and I agree it probably isn't...), I just ended up using the `cbuilder` getter on the `Module::Build` object to manually do the compilation. With only one C file, I figured it was a small sin, and this lets me move on!

```
my $b = $builder->cbuilder();

my $obj_file = $b->compile(
    source => 'src/myfile.c',
    extra_compiler_flags => ['-std=c99'],
    include_dirs => ['/my/path/zeromq-3.2.4/include']
);

my $lib_file = $b->link_executable(
    objects => $obj_file,
    extra_linker_flags => [
        '-lpthread',
        '-L/my/path/sw/zmq/lib/',
        '-lzmq'
    ],
    exe_file => 'my_file'
);
```